# Factorising polynomial with remainder theorem where constant is zero

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Am a newbie with additional math. When factorising polynomials with a constant of zero using the remainder theorem, the only method I can think of at the moment is random hit and miss since we have two unknown factors (for a cubic).

Please advise how, for a polynomial such as $f(x)= x^3-x^2-2x$, I should go about finding the other two factors (not x), as efficiently as possible?

Many thanks.

Comment: `we have two unknown factors (for a cubic)` Once you factor out $\,x\,$ you are left with a quadratic.

Comment: Oh no why didn't that come to me! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)= x^3-x^2-2x=x(x^2-x-2)=x(x-2)(x+1)$$

The other factors are $x-2$ and $x+1$ because $x=2$ and $x=-1$ make $f(x)=0.$

Thus the remainder of  your polynomial in  dividing by $x+1$ and $x-2$ is zero.